# Limit Character in FreeTextBox line

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've known many ways to limit the characters inputed inside the Textbox control or Freetextbox control.

How can I limit the character in each line (row) of FreeTextBox control???

For example, if the character in a line is 200, then it auto go to the next line

Best regard!

Comment: implement TextChanged event . .try to calculate the number character being entered and place your accordingly

Comment: I think it's better to do it on client side, make a javascript that monitors the textbox changes

Comment: You might wanna see this post: http://forums.freetextbox.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=9577#post9577

Comment: @woodykiddy HTML markup??? where I can put this line: < b > Wrap Text </ b >< input id ="Checkbox1" type ="checkbox" onclick ="FTBDesignWrap('FreeTextBox1', this.checked);" />. I really dont know???

Comment: It's a checkbox control that does text wrapping. It's supposed to be on the same page where you use FTB control.

Comment: @woodykiddy sorry for a lot of silly question, but can you tell me how can I put that html line in my aspx page. And the Checkbox control in aspx isnt has onclick method

Comment: Just copy and paste it into aspx page, as aspx page is made of html controls and asp.net controls

Comment: @woodykiddy thank you, It can fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Hello this tricky way to handle by Javascript or JQuery..
Please follow below code for same with Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtData" CssClass="text-limit" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" style="width:500px; height:150px;"></asp:TextBox> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var charactorPerLine = 20;
    $(function () {
        $(".text-limit").keydown(function (event) {
            // Allow: backspace(8), delete(46), tab(9), escape(27) and enter(13) 
            if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13]) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            else {

                if ($(this).val().lastIndexOf("\n") == -1) {
                    if ($(this).val().length >= charactorPerLine) {
                        $(this).val($(this).val() + "\n");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (($(this).val().length - $(this).val().lastIndexOf("\n")) >= charactorPerLine {
                        $(this).val($(this).val() + "\n");
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, no idea for freeTextbox